# Grails console open with default or last file

Tags: grails, grails-web-console

Is there a way to configure grails console to open either with default file or with last opened file?

Comment: I don't think so, but `file > open` should open the last folder.

Comment: @SérgioMichels I know, but it is just tedious to reopen same file every time

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about closing the console every time you bounce the app or do any kind of change that would involve a compile/run-app, then you can use the [console plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/console) instead.

You do not have to close the browser while the restart is in process. I hope this would quench the thirst for your console to some extent. :)